# How do I set different endpoints for app in Google Play test/live?

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-play

I have an app which I want to release through the Google Play Store, but want to have the web service point to a different URL - between TEST and LIVE; can this be done? and how?

```
TEST APP -> www.myTESTserver.co.uk/service.asmx
LIVE APP -> www.myLIVEserver.co.uk/service.asmx
```

We have previously been building two APK files for upload, one with each URL set, but thought that there must be a better (correct) way of doing this.

The development process, therefore should be that the app uses www.myTESTserver.co.uk whilst being developed on my PC and when uploaded to the Play Store "TEST" area, but switch to www.myLIVEserver.co.uk when we promote it to LIVE (publicly available)

Comment: When do you want to put different URL.

Comment: The URL needs to switch (ideally) when we promote the APP from Google Play TEST to LIVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using something like [Firebase Remote config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to configure the URL per version code.